# PHP/SQL - Returning query results and counts

Tags: php, mysql

SQL/PHP noob.  I've looked up a number of questions, but none seem to help get me what I need.

I have a front-end for a database that runs SQL queries based off the state of a checkbox.  I want the SQL query to return both the results and the result count (into a variable) with a single query.

If I run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
event.event_id as 'Event ID',
event.event_group_id as 'Group ID',
abs_path.abs_path as 'Path\Filename',

FROM 
event.event_group
LEFT JOIN event.event using (event_group_id)
LEFT JOIN file_info.abs_path using (abs_path_id)

WHERE event.timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
LIMIT 40
```

I get all the results to the query.  But if I run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
count(event.event_id) as 'rowcount',
event.event_id as 'Event ID',
event.event_group_id as 'Group ID',
abs_path.abs_path as 'Path\Filename',

FROM 
event.event_group
LEFT JOIN event.event using (event_group_id)
LEFT JOIN file_info.abs_path using (abs_path_id)

WHERE event.timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
LIMIT 40
```

I only get a single result with 'rowcount' being the first column, but if I take it out, I get all my results:

[image: sql]

I want to be able to get the total row count and save it into a variable, while also pulling down the results to display on the screen.

I'm using the following to fetch the query:

```
$result = $database->query($sql);
```

How can I do the query and the count at the same time while saving just the total results into $rowcount ?  If you look at the bottom left corner of the 2nd image, SQL Query Browser displays the total number in the query.  I want that number.  How can I get it?

Thanks

Comment: You have to add `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Try to post things in your question in plain-text in their most minimal form. This question has huge, mostly empty screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of rows and result in PHP.
After executing the query you will get result let's say `$res`.

You can use that to fetch number of rows.
If using mysqli library use

`mysqli_num_rows ( $res );`

If you are using PDO you will have to run 2 queries one to fetch the values and other to fetch the count.

[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a solution by sql, may not a better solution, but try it;)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
event.event_id as 'Event ID',
event.event_group_id as 'Group ID',
abs_path.abs_path as 'Path\Filename',
@cnt:=@cnt + 1 as cnt

FROM 
event.event_group
LEFT JOIN event.event using (event_group_id)
LEFT JOIN file_info.abs_path using (abs_path_id),
(SELECT @cnt:=0) var

WHERE event.timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
LIMIT 40
```

And you can get count of query result by `cnt` of the last record.

Answer (score 0):

When using `COUNT` function your query is being automatically grouped.
Try using `$rowcount = $result->fetchColumn();` and don't `COUNT` it in SQL.